# Let $G$ be a group of order $1365$. Prove $G$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I'm having troubles with this.

Let G be a group of order $1365$. Is $G$ simple?
Normally, we aim to find a single Sylow p-subgroup and since its normal, we get the results.

However, factoring $1365=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13$ gives me(for $n_p$ being the number of Sylow p subgroups):

$n_3=\{1,7,13,91\}$

$n_5=\{1,21,91\}$

$n_7=\{1,15\}$

$n_{13}=\{1,105\}$

I might have missed some, but nonetheless we can't be sure that any of these Sylow p subgroups are normal. Then perhaps the group is simple?

How can i solve this task?

Comment: There is an abelian group with this order, and of course it is not simple since it doesn't have a prime order.

Comment: @Bernard Doesn't that imply that every group of non-prime order is not simple? Theres always the cyclic group $Z_n$ for any order and its always abelian.

Comment: No, this implies that, for each non-prime $n$, there is a non-simple group of order $n$. It's possible for a simple group to have the same order as a non-simple group! For example, $Z_{60}$ has the same order as $A_5$.

Comment: That is an awesome result. How could we prove that abelian groups of non-prime order are not simple?

Comment: For abelian groups, certainly. For non-abelian groups, a consequence of Feit-Thomson's theorem is that every simple (non-abelian) simple group has even order.

Comment: As a hint for the general group of order $1365$:  if there were $105$ $13-$Sylow groups, then their union would contain $105\times 12+1=1261$ group elements.  That only leaves $105$ elements.  So now look at the $7-$Sylow groups and, if necessary, the $5-$Sylow groups.

Comment: @Hristmar Let $A$ be a nontrivial abelian group of non-prime order. Prove that it contains a subgroup of prime order. This subgroup must be normal (why?), therefore $A$ is not simple.

Comment: @Hristmar: The proof can be done with the structure theorme of finite abelian groups, which has to do with the *Chinese remainder theorem*

Comment: @Bernard  Feit-Thomson might, possibly, be overkill here.

Comment: @lulu: Sure, but if you know it, you know the answer, so you don't hesitate and can begin to look for a simple proof.

Comment: @Bernard  Agreed.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk My brain refuses to work. Ofcourse they arent simple, every subgroup is normal in an abelian group. And since the order can be factored into primes, by Sylow theorems we know that those prime order subgroups exist. 

Thanks for your help guys. This was really useful.

Comment: Quick note: Sylow subgroups need not have prime order. However, every nontrivial group has a subgroup of prime order. This doesn't matter for your argument, though.

Comment: Every group is either simple or not simple. What is the question?

Comment: I completely agree with @JCAA on this. What is the question? I guess there are plenty of comments and an accepted answer, so somebody must have some idea of what is being asked.

Comment: I believe the question was something like "I've been given a homework problem which asks me to prove either that every group of order $1365$ is simple or that every group of order $1365$ is not simple. Here is my work so far. How do I continue from here?" The title does not communicate this correctly, but it was at least clear to me once I read the body of the post.

Comment: The statement in the original title was trivially true. The edited title does not make sense.

Comment: Is this really that important? We all know what the question is. I edited the title.

Comment: Seriously yes, I believe that stating a problem accurately is important. Firstly, if the question is unclear, then many readers will not want to waste their time trying to figure out what it means. Secondly, I have to say that after reading questions on MSA for several years, I have noticed that an imprecisely stated question often indicates a lack of understanding by the poster. But  I agree that in this case you made a reasonable attempt to solve it, and it has now been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @lulu suggests, this is a situation where we should apply a simple counting argument. This is a common theme in Sylow-theorem exercises.

Suppose for contradiction that there is a simple group $G$ of order $1365$. For this group, we must have $n_3, n_5, n_7, n_{13} > 1$, so by your computations we get

$$n_3 \geq 7$$
$$n_5 \geq 21$$
$$n_7 = 15$$
$$n_{13} = 105$$

This means the group has $1260=105\times 12$ elements of order $13$, $90$ elements of order $7$, at least $84$ elements of order $5$, and at least $14$ elements of order $3$ (make sure you understand how to prove all of this!!)

In total, we have accounted for at least $1260 + 90 + 84 + 14 = 1448$ distinct elements of $G$. This is impossible, because $\lvert G \rvert < 1448$.